# Pass Strings from one activity to normal class

Tags: java, android

In my main activity I use google location services and I get longitude and 
latitude.

```
Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

if (mLastLocation != null) {
    String longtitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    String latitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
```

As you can see I have 2 strings with data inside. I want to pass this strings to other **normal class**. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Might want to learn some basic Java first

Answer (score 1):

Well you can just pass it as params to the other class:

```
myClassObject.myFunction(string1, string2);
```

Or if the object has not been created, you can write your own constructor, and give it the necessary params:

```
new MyClass(string1, string);
```

or you can add the params via setter to the class:

```
myClassObject.setString1(string1);
myClassObject.setString2(string2);
myClassObject.myFunction();
```